# Assertj verify that a field of each items in a collection is always null

Tags: java, assertj

I'm looking for a solution to check that each items in a collection have the field `expectedNullField` null.

The following doesn't work:

`assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNullField").isNull();`

Note that the following works as expected:
`assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNotNullField").isNotNull();`

Anybody to help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `assertThat(aCollection).filteredOn("expectedNullField", not(null)).isEmpty();`

Comment: It works but it's not easy to read :S

Comment: Then I would use Conditions http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html, it's more verbose but easier to read

Answer (score 7):

If you know the size (let's say it is 3) you can use

```
assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNullField")
                       .containsOnly(null, null, null);
```

or if you are only interested in checking that there is a null value

```
assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNullField")
                       .containsNull();
```

Note that you can't use:

```
    assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNullField")
                           .containsOnly(null);
```

because it is ambiguous (containsOnly specifying a varargs params).

I might consider adding `containsOnlyNullElements()` in AssertJ to overcome the compiler error above.

Comment: `assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNullField").containsOnly(null);` is my favorite (because of readability), but it give me the following error (in addition to the compiler warning) `java.lang.NullPointerException: The array of values to look for should not be null`

Comment: that's because it tries to convert null to a varargs which is an array of value that should not be null. you could use it by casting null to the element collection type, ex: `assertThat(aCollection).extracting("stringField")
                           .containsOnly((String)null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Condition

```
Condition<YourClass> nullField = new Condition<>("expecting field to be null") {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(YourClass value) {
    return value.getField() == null;
  }
};

assertThat(aCollection).have(nullField);
```

which might be easier to read than the other solution

```
assertThat(aCollection).filteredOn("expectedNullField", not(null)).isEmpty();
```

Comment: It doesn't work: `java.lang.NullPointerException: The array of values to look for should not be null`

Comment: Back to Conditions then I guess :(

Comment: Maybe the fact that `assertThat(aCollection).extracting("expectedNullField").isNull();` doesn't work as I expect it to is a bug ?

Comment: My understanding is that it would check the collection and not its elements. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version `2.5.0` (the one that `Spring Boot` uses)